# Parsing command line arguments in Python: getting a KeyError

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-arguments

I am trying execute my Python script as:

```
python series.py supernatural 4 6
```

```
Supernatural : TV Series name 
4 : season number
6 : episode number
```

Now in my script I am using the above three arguments to fetch the title of the episode:

```
import tvrage.api
import sys

a =  sys.argv[1] 
b = sys.argv[2]
c =  sys.argv[3]

temp = tvrage.api.Show(a)
name  = temp.season(b).episode(c)  # Line:19
print ( name.title)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
File "series.py", line 19, in <module>:
  name = super.season(b).episode(c) 
File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\tvrage\api.py", line 212, in season
  return self.episodes[n] KeyError: '4'
```

I am using Python 2.6.

Comment: actually the error is pointing to api i am using but if u want error is                                                                     ` File "series.py", line 19, in <module>
    name  = super.season(b).episode(c)
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\tvrage\api.py", line 212, in season`
    return self.episodes[n]
KeyError: '4'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Python TVRage API](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-tvrage/0.1.4) is expecting integers, not strings (which is what you get from `argv`):

```
name = temp.season(int(b)).episode(int(c))
```

will correct the error, if season 4 episode 6 exists.

You should take a look at the command line parsing modules that come with Python. For 3.2 / 2.7 or newer, use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html). For older versions, use [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html). If you already know C's `getopt`, use [getopt](http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html).

Answer (score 3):

A `KeyError` means you're trying to access an item in a dictionary that doesn't exist. This code will generate the error, because there's no `'three'` key in the dictionary:

```
>>> d = dict(one=1, two=2)
>>> d
{'two': 2, 'one': 1}
>>> d['three']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'three'
```

See [the Python Wiki entry on KeyErrors](http://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError).

Comment: That's a fine description of a `KeyError` but doesn't answer the question -- it doesn't tell him _why_ that key doesn't exist in the dictionary.