# KeyError while parsing command line arguments

Tags: python, cmd, command-line-arguments, python-3.7

I've been trying to parse arguments on the command line. 
In the code which I've been trying to run.

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--prototxt ", required=True,
    help="path to Caffe 'deploy' prototxt file")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True,
    help="path to Caffe pre-trained model")
```

So, I go to that directory using `cd` then, I've tried

```
python people_counter.py --prototxt C:\Users\mustafa\Downloads\people-counting-opencv\people-counting-opencv\mobilenet_ssd --model C:\Users\mustafa\Downloads\people-counting-opencv\people-counting-opencv\mobilenet_ssd
```

And here is the error message:

```
[INFO] loading model...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "people_counter.py", line 49, in <module>
    net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["prototxt"], args["model"])
KeyError: 'prototxt'
```

I am sure that both paths are true. 
[image: paths]
EDIT: I've seen that I had defined `prototxt` with space. So I removed it.

Comment: It might be the extra space you have in `"--prototxt "`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing command line arguments in Python: getting a KeyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395488/parsing-command-line-arguments-in-python-getting-a-keyerror)

Comment: I think you mean `args.prototxt` but you also should remove the space from `"--prototxt "`.